# libgdx fake 3d shadows

Tags: 3d, libgdx, shadows

I'm writing 3d game with `libgdx`, and want to add fake 2d shadows on bottom of models. Now I'm using 2 planes with shadow texture and draw them a bit upper then floor planes. Everything is going ok, but when 2 shadow planes overlaps, there is a weird graphical artifact, because shadow planes have same Y(vertical) coordinate. What i need to do to avoid this? Maybe some texture on floor plane projection? If so - how?

example image [image: http://itmages.ru/image/view/1497735/17ea1cdd]

UPDATED:
So i found another solution. You can use circle mesh for shadows instead of quad and don't let them overlap.

[image]

Comment: nb this is called "z-fighting" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dirty but working solution is just giving them a different Y position each. A very very very little difference, just enough to fix your problem but to be unnoticeable.

Comment: Just a little question to this, as i am also about to create a 3D game: Is it better to set this y value unique for every object with shadow, or only change it, if it is near to any other shadow object?

Comment: If the first one is easily achievable (not many objects), yep that one. If not, then just change it when they overlap. Always go for the easier solution.